# Defining Array Size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to define the size of a multidimensional array as a constant. What would be the best way to do this please? In the example below, MY_CONSTANT would be equal to 2. Can this constant be determined before run time?

```
#define MY_CONSTANT <what goes here?>

std::string myArray[][3] = { 
{"test", "test", "test"},
{"test", "test", "test"}
};
```

Comment: `const std::size_t array_size = 2;`? BTW, prefer `std::array` when you have *constant* size array, else `std::vector` (or `std::deque`).

Comment: In C++, you should prefer `const` variables to `#define`. They can be used as compile-time constants, and also respect scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might use [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) to get the size of the array at compile time:

```
std::string myArray[][3] = { 
  {"test", "test", "test"},
  {"test", "test", "test"}
};

const std::size_t myArraySize = std::extent<decltype(myArray)>::value;
```

The preprocessor will not be able to define the value directly. Of course you could use

```
#define MY_CONSTANT std::extent<decltype(myArray)>::value
```

but I guess that's not *really* what you want to do.

Comment: const std::size_t MY_CONSTANT = std::extent<decltype(myArray)>();

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use a `constexpr` function to initialise a compile-time constant:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> 
constexpr size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) {return N;}

constexpr size_t MY_CONSTANT = array_size(myArray);
```

(or use `std::extent` as another answer suggests; I didn't know about that).

Historically, you would need to initialise it with a constant expression like

```
const size_t MY_CONSTANT = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using C++, better use `const` instead of `#define`.

`#define` is a preprocessor directive which will perform textual substitution before compilation.

`const int` create a read only variable.
so better use something like: `const size_t arraySize = 2;`

"Can this constant be determined before run time?"

you would have to use dynamically allocated arrays using `new`
or better use `vector` from STL